# AudioKit Apply Gain to Mono PCM Buffer

Tags: audiokit

I have a mono audio file. Which I am opening and trying to apply gain with the following code:

```
let inputFile = try! AVAudioFile(forReading: url)
let settings = inputFile.fileFormat.settings
let outputFile = try! AVAudioFile(forWriting: outputURL, settings: settings)
let sourceBuffer = try! AVAudioPCMBuffer(file: inputFile)

let engine = AudioEngine()
let player = AudioPlayer()
let compressor = Compressor(player)
compressor.masterGain = AUValue(gain)

engine.output = compressor

compressor.start()

do {
    try engine.start()
    player.start()
    player.scheduleBuffer(sourceBuffer!, at: nil, options: [], completionHandler: nil)
    try engine.renderToFile(outputFile, duration: inputFile.duration)
} catch {
    completion(.failure(error))
}
```

`player.scheduleBuffer` crashes with the following exception:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'required condition is false: _outputFormat.channelCount == buffer.format.channelCount'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

But how do I set the correct number of channels?

I already tried `Settings.audioFormat = inputFile.fileFormat` or `Settings.audioFormat = sourceBuffer!.format` before initializing the `AudioEngine`. Same results.

I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: I have the same question, have you figured out a solution by any chance? Thanks!